# Strange background image "effect" in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm noticing an odd effect in jQuery Mobile when viewing a page's background image on a low resolution screen (or resizing your browser's window to simulate a small screen). When navigating to a page with a background image, the image appears near the bottom of the screen for a split second, before "jumping" up to the center of the screen (it *should* appear in the center of the screen right from the start).

I set up a fiddle to demonstrate what I'm referring to. To get the full effect, first resize the fiddle "Result" window (bottom right of the screen) to where it's approximately the size of the div with the red background. Then click on the "Image page" button.

http://jsfiddle.net/FgVz8/3/

What causes the background image to have this "jerky" behavior? And more importantly, any ideas how I can fix it?

It wouldn't be a big deal if it was just a single image, but I'm building an image gallery with back/forward buttons, and every single image (each on a separate jQM "page") that is navigated to exhibits this strange effect, so it makes for a rather "unsmooth" user experience... especially when viewing multiple images one after another.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: it looks like Stack Overflow won't let me link out to JSFiddle unless I also post my code here, so here's my code...

HTML body...

```
<div id="home_page" data-role="page">
    <div id="content" data-role="content">
        <a href="#image_page" data-role="button">Image page</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="image_page" data-role="page">
    <p>Test 123...</p>
</div>
```

CSS...

```
#content {

    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;    

}

#image_page { 

    background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Logo_Google_2013_Official.svg/2000px-Logo_Google_2013_Official.svg.png);
    background-size: contain;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Simply, because content div's height is "0" during changing pages. Its' height is set once the page is fully visible. How to fix it? 1) set bg image to page 2) add bg image to content div on `pagecontainershow` and remove it on `pagecontainerhide`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Omar. I couldn't get "pagecontainershow" to work at all for some reason, so I tried adding the BG image to the content div on "pageshow", but I got the same result. I did finally figure out a solution though. I simply added the CSS rule "background-attachment: fixed" to the page that holds the BG image. Works perfectly now :)

Comment: Good to hear so :) this is what I meant, add bg img to page div not content div.